# SVN throwing "Error resolving case of " for all local network requests

Tags: svn, pipe

Just for knowledge purpose, i am writing a UI for SVN using C++ pipe. But when i execute (using computer name):

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" info --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD https://myserver2/svn/test_svnplugin_unity/trunk
```

OR i tried using IP

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" info --username satbirs --password satbirs https://192.168.10.xxx/svn/test_svnplugin_unity/trunk
```

Computer myserver2 OR 192.168.10.xxx is in my local network. I have VisualSVN (v3.9.0) installed as server and using `https://` to access repositories.

Both above commands are working when i try from Windows 10 DOS console. I am using SVN binaries provided by TortoiseSVN (v1.10.0) client itself.

Also, when i execute the same below command on my working directory, it returns the correct output:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe"  info --username satbirs --password satbirs "D:\WorkingCopyTrunk\trunk"
```

This ensures that my pipe code is working fine.

I think something is wrong with SVN accessing network computer.

Am i missing something related to pipe or SVN command?

Comment: What VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN versions do you use?

Comment: @bahrep, TortoiseSVN (v1.10.0) and VisualSVN (v3.9.0)